# Radare2 is showing weird disassembly as compared to disassembly of gcc

Tags: radare2, c, gcc

Today i was playing around with c code in r2.
I compiled a file which had the following code.

```
#include <stdio.h>

int main(){
        int a=9;
        float b=1.1;
        int sum;
        sum = a+b;
        printf("%d", sum);
        return 0;
```

When I compiled it with gdb with the -S option, the assembly code that I got was normal, it had call to printf, some floating operations everything normal, but when I loaded it to r2 and runned aaa then pdf @main, it showed weird assembly which had no call to printf, only a single floating operation. I don't know why is it happening. If anyone of you can explain me, It would be great.
Here is the weird disassembly :

```
┌ 108: int main (int argc, char **argv, char **envp);
│           0x00402070      83ec1c         sub esp, 0x1c
│           0x00402073      8b442420       mov eax, dword [esp + 0x20]
│           0x00402077      c744240c801f.  mov dword [esp + 0xc], 0x1f80 ; [0x1f80:4]=-1
│           0x0040207f      83f8fd         cmp eax, 0xfffffffd
│       ┌─< 0x00402082      7431           je 0x4020b5
│       │   0x00402084      83f8fc         cmp eax, 0xfffffffc
│      ┌──< 0x00402087      743a           je 0x4020c3
│      ││   0x00402089      85c0           test eax, eax
│     ┌───< 0x0040208b      7448           je 0x4020d5
│     │││   ; CODE XREF from main @ 0x4020da
│    ┌────> 0x0040208d      83f8ff         cmp eax, 0xffffffff
│   ┌─────< 0x00402090      742d           je 0x4020bf
│   │╎│││   0x00402092      83f8fe         cmp eax, 0xfffffffe
│  ┌──────< 0x00402095      7436           je 0x4020cd
│  ││╎│││   0x00402097      d920           fldenv [eax]
│  ││╎│││   0x00402099      0fb7401c       movzx eax, word [eax + 0x1c]
│  ││╎│││   0x0040209d      8944240c       mov dword [esp + 0xc], eax
│  ││╎│││   ; CODE XREFS from main @ 0x4020c1, 0x4020d3
│ ┌───────> 0x004020a1      f60524704000.  test byte [0x407024], 0x10  ; [0x407024:1]=0
│ ────────< 0x004020a8      7405           je 0x4020af
│ ╎││╎│││   0x004020aa      0fae54240c     ldmxcsr dword [esp + 0xc]
│ ────────> 0x004020af      31c0           xor eax, eax
│ ╎││╎│││   0x004020b1      83c41c         add esp, 0x1c
│ ╎││╎│││   0x004020b4      c3             ret
│ ╎││╎││└─> 0x004020b5      c70514404000.  mov dword [0x404014], 0xffffffff ; [0x404014:4]=-1
│ ╎│└─────> 0x004020bf      dbe3           fninit
│ ────────< 0x004020c1      ebde           jmp 0x4020a1
│ ╎│ ╎│└──> 0x004020c3      c70514404000.  mov dword [0x404014], 0xfffffffe ; [0x404014:4]=-1
│ ╎└──────> 0x004020cd      ff159c814000   call dword [0x40819c]
│ └───────< 0x004020d3      ebcc           jmp 0x4020a1
│    ╎└───> 0x004020d5      a114404000     mov eax, dword [0x404014]   ; [0x404014:4]=-1
└    └────< 0x004020da      ebb1           jmp 0x40208d
```

Comment: I was not able to reproduce what is shown here. What version of GCC did you use? and what arguments were used with GCC when the binary was compiled?

Comment: Are you sure you’re disassembling the same binary?

Comment: i found why was this happening.
It was happening because I decompiled with radare2 in windows
It's some problem with windows or something